# UISplitView with Multiple Tableviews

Tags: ios, uitableview, xib

I have a Splitview with a Tabbar with 5 buttons, in the left side.
Every tab has a navigation controller with a tableview.

Some premises:

- App is not built with storyboard
- I do not understand the architecture of the Apple sample code "MultipleDetailViews.xcodeproj"

Button 5,  header file.

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
@class DetailViewiPad;

@interface TAB5 : UIViewController <UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate> 
{
    DetailViewiPad *detailViewController;
}

@property (nonatomic, strong) IBOutlet DetailViewiPad *detailViewController;

@end
```

Button 5,  implement file.

```
@implementation TAB5

@synthesize detailViewController;

[some code...]

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    if ([key isEqualToString:@"A"]) {

        [detailViewController setDetailItem:[websites objectAtIndex:row]];  

    } else if ([key isEqualToString:@"B"]) {

        TableView2 *controller = [[TableView2 alloc] initWithNibName:@"TableView2" bundle:nil];

         [self.navigationController pushViewController:controller animated:YES];
    }
```

**Option "A" WORKS PERFECT, the Detail View (right side) shows its content!**

If you select Option "B" (you navigate to TableView2) and then you select some row:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

        DetailViewiPad *detailViewController =
        [[DetailViewiPad alloc] initWithNibName:@"DetailViewiPad" bundle:nil];

         [detailViewController setDetailItem:[websites objectAtIndex:row]];
```

**DETAIL VIEW NOT RESPOND.** If you set a breakpoint you can see that program flow goes to detail view and it passes data but you can not see updates in the view (iPad device).

**Repeat: program flow goes to detail view and it passes data but not refresh the screen.**

It seems like some problem of connection between new class (TableView2.h, TableView2.m, TableView2.xib) and the detail view. Some kind of delegate problem.

Answer (score 0):

**I found it !!!!**

**Fantastic !!!**

Premise: my detail view it calls DetailViewiPad

- DetailViewiPad.h
- DetailViewiPad.m
- DetailViewiPad.xib

That is the key, the magical code:

```
DetailViewiPad *detailViewController  = (DetailViewiPad*)self.splitViewController.delegate;

[detailViewController setDetailItem:[websites objectAtIndex:row]];
```

It is INCORRECT the sentence:

```
DetailViewiPad *detailViewController = [[DetailViewiPad alloc] initWithNibName:@"DetailViewiPad" bundle:nil];
```

**The key to obtain the delegation from subsequents Tableviews to detail View (in iPad Splitview) is:**

```
DetailViewiPad *detailViewController  = (DetailViewiPad*)self.splitViewController.delegate;
```

Comment: If someone needs the full code, you can send me an email. I will explain you in detail the construction of the "MainWindow-iPad.xib" and the Detail View, etcetera.